# How to italicise numbers in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, tex

The desired result:

[The number "3" is italicised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMsVs.png)

A failed attempt:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.rcParams.update(
    {"text.usetex": False}
)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r"$\it{FOXP3}^+$Helios$^+$ naïve Treg", size=25, ha="center")
ax.axis("off")
```

[The number "3" is not italicised](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER7GA.png)

A successful but awkward attempt:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r"FOXP3$^+$$\rm{Helios}^+$ $\rm{naïve \ Treg}$", style='italic', size=25, ha="center")
ax.axis("off")
```

[The number "3" is italicised by marking everything else "roman"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fOF9o.png)

A successful but inconvenient attempt:

```py
plt.rcParams.update(
    {"text.usetex": True}
)
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.text(0.5, 0.5, r"\textit{FOXP3}$^+$Helios$^+$ naïve Treg", size=25, ha="center")
ax.axis("off")
```

[The number "3" is italicised using TeX](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v8wvM.png)

Matplotlib version: 3.4.2

How to italicise numbers using Matplotlib's native mathtext instead of TeX?

Comment: The default math font is italic so why did you change it?  If you insist on changing it, you can use \mathit. https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/text/mathtext.html

Comment: @JodyKlymak Yes the default value for "mathtext.default" is "it". However, numbers are not italicised by default. \mathit does not italicise numbers either. I have now edited my code to avoid confusions on this.